# Can anyone help me to create mockRepository for my findAll createQueryBuilder service method?

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

This is the first time of mine written a unit test for a nest js application. Can anyone help me to create a mockRepository for my findAll createQueryBuilder service method? I am trying to develop a mockRepository.But it's not working.

This is my findAll createQueryBuilder service method.

```
async findAll(getPaginationParamDto: PaginationParamDto): Promise<GetCcAdminResponseDto> {
    try {
      const result = this.ccAdminRepo
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .leftJoinAndSelect('CcAdmin.userId', 'userId')
        .where({ isArchived: false });
      const total = await result.getCount();
      const totalPages =
        total % getPaginationParamDto.limit === 0
          ? total / getPaginationParamDto.limit
          : Math.floor(total / getPaginationParamDto.limit) + 1;

      const data = await result.offset(getPaginationParamDto.offset).limit(getPaginationParamDto.limit).getMany();
      // Create custom response according to swagger
      const customData = data.map((data) => {
        if (data.userId) {
          const userId = data.userId.userId;
          return {
            ...data,
            userId: userId,
          };
        }
      });
      return {
        total,
        totalPages,
        data: customData,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

This is my mockRepository and test function.

```
  const mockRepository = {
    createQueryBuilder: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      leftJoinAndSelect: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      where: jest.fn().mockReturnThis() as unknown,
    })),
    result: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      offset: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      take: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    })),
    total: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      result: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        getCount: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      })),
    })),
    count: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(2),
    findOneOrFail: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(CcAdminData[0]),
    findOne: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(CcAdminData[0]),
    create: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(createCcAdminInput),
    save: jest.fn().mockImplementation(),
    remove: jest.fn().mockImplementation(),
  };

describe('findAll', () => {
    it('should return an array of Cc Admin with totalPages and  total', async () => {
      const data = await service.findAll(getPaginationParamDto);
      console.log(data);
      expect(data).toEqual(getCcAdminResponseDto);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Show your module as well

Comment: This is exactly why you don't mock what you don't own - look at how complex your test doubles are! Push that below a facade that you own, that reflects your domain and that you can much more easily mock (decoupling your logic from the details of a third-party API as a bonus), then use _integration_-level testing to ensure the right thing happens behind that.